# como le quito horas? al formato carbon o en la funcion laravel

Tags: php, laravel, carbon, blade

```
 public static function NotificaCalendarioCitas($profesional_id)
{
    $listaCitas = null;
    $hoy = Carbon::now()->addHour(5);

    $citasAsignadas = CitaProfesional::where('profesional_id', $profesional_id)
                                    ->where('tiempo_fin_cita', '>=', $hoy)
                                    ->get();


    if( $citasAsignadas->count() > 0 && !empty($citasAsignadas  ))
    {
        Alert::warning('Revise su Agenda', 'Usted tiene un evento pendiente')
            ->persistent('Cerar')
            ->autoclose(6000);
        $listaCitas = $citasAsignadas;

    }
   dd($citasAsignadas);

    return $citasAsignadas;
}
```

este es la función

```
@if($calendarCitas != null && $calendarCitas->count() > 0)

                        @foreach($calendarCitas as $cita)
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <strong>{{ $cita->usuario }}</strong>
                                <br />

                                <strong><small>Inicio:</small></strong> {{ $cita->tiempo_inicio_cita}} 

                                <br />
                                <strong><small>Final:</small></strong> {{ $cita->tiempo_fin_cita }}
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <p><strong>No hay citas asignadas</strong></p>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

y este el blade

Comment: ¿Quitarle horas a qué? hay mucho código...

Comment: la primera es la funcion

Comment: el segundo es el blade

Comment: Pero eso no responde la pregunta, ¿a qué variable le quiere quitar horas?

Comment: tiempo_inicio_cita

Comment: tiempo_fin_cita  quiero quitarles 5 horas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quitarle o restarle horas a una instancia de Carbon, se utiliza el método `subHours()`:

```
$cita->tiempo_inicio_cita->subHours(5);

$cita->tiempo_fin_cita->subHours(5);
```

La información completa está en la documentación de Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

---

Para que Laravel reconozca que los campos son una fecha, debe declararlo en el modelo respectivo:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'tiempo_inicio_cita',
    'tiempo_fin_cita'
];
```

Comment: Call to a member function subHours()

Comment: por que es un blade

Comment: "Call to a member function subHours() on string"

Comment: ¿un blade? creo que tiene los conceptos confundidos. Laravel por defecto administra las horas como instancias de Carbon, a menos que no las tenga configuradas correctamente en el modelo.

Comment: No existe tal cosa como «un blade», probablemente no le ha informado a Laravel que sus campos son fechas. Revise la edición que hice a mi pregunta.

Comment: si era lo de date